# Did Ronald Wayne ever disclose his reasons for leaving the company so early?

Tags: history

I’m curious about Apple history, and this has puzzled me for a long time.

For any Apple fans like me, it’s a famous fact that Ronald Wayne sold his share of Apple very early on for only $800. Does anyone know why he sold it? I haven’t been able to figure this one out.

Comment: Since you are curious about Apple history, I suggest you browse through [Folklore.org](https://www.folklore.org), a Web site containing dozens of anecdotes about the development of the original Macintosh. The Web Site is created and maintained by Andy Hertzfeld, a member of the original Apple Macintosh development team during the 1980s. There are a lot of first hand accounts that you will find interesting. A lot of Apple history is also collected in a book titled [Revolution in the Valley](https://www.amazon.com/Revolution-Valley-Insanely-Great-Story/dp/0596007191).

Comment: @NimeshNeema Ooh, sounds cool! I’ll take a look.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about using Apple technology or products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ronald Wayne's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Wayne) page:

> Wayne received a 10% stake in Apple. Less than two weeks later, on April 12, 1976 he relinquished his equity for US$800. Legally, all members of a partnership are personally responsible for any debts incurred by any partner; unlike Jobs and Wozniak, then 21 and 25, Wayne had personal assets that potential creditors could seize. The failure of a slot machine company he had started five years earlier also contributed to his decision to exit the partnership.

[Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20000817234627/http://www.woz.org/letters/pirates/09.html) an interview by Steve Wozniak, where he describes situation leading to Wayne's exit.